# Plane Canopy from two paths

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make a canopy for a plane / space fighter (you know, something like [this](https://live.staticflickr.com/3236/2856829450_226e3eed65_b.jpg)[image]) and I am struggling to get the basic shape right. My latest attempt was using two paths:
[image]

These map out the basic shape, but I still need to connect them in a cylindrical shape. Is that possible and am I going about it (-> the making of the canopy) about the right way or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

- Join the curves into one mesh object (I started with 2 separate curves)
- make sure top profile and side profile have the same amount of vertices before the next step
- <kbd>TAB</kbd> to enter Edit mode, <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > **Bridge Edge Loops**
- play around with the settings, in my crude example I just changed the number of cuts and changed **Interpolation** to **Blend Path**
- add mirror modifier with **Merge** on

[image]